# Do I focus the offtank/tank if he is fed?

Tags: league-of-legends

When engaging in a teamfight what do you do if the most fed/most damaging champion on the opposition is a tank who does godly damage regardless of building straight health and tankiness, such as Darius.

What exactly do you do if it's recommended to leave the tank until last and focus on the squishies.It will leave you completely vulnerable and leaving 'insert tank here_____' (eg.Darius) with a satisfying cleanup.

What can be done to overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focusing the tank **can** work, but I would not recommend it.  You need careful preparation and coordination to pull it off, and if you fail its just painful.

The tank is generally going to be on the front lines trying to initiate; Poke him mercilessly.  If he's stacking armor/mr, pick up last whisper/void staff.  If he's stacking HP, have your ADC pick up a HP shredding item or two.  Use your CC to keep the rest of his team busy while you burn him quickly.

Keep in mind, **if the tank is fed, that likely means the rest of the enemy team is not**.  Pure tanks don't tend to do a lot of damage, even when fed; Generally a tank's job is to cause disruption in the enemy team.  Darius is a bruiser, and he's most dangerous when built this way; his damage as pure tank is actually on the low side, and he's a glass cannon when built as pure damage.

#### In general for all teamfights:

- Before the teamfight starts, put some solid poke damage into the enemy.
- Try to force the teamfight on your terms, not on theirs.
- It may be necessary to disengage and reengage during the fight;  If Darius starts dunking people, snare him and back off until his ult has reset, then go back in.
- Outmaneuver them and coordinate your CC and AE abilities carefully.  If you're worried about the fed tank, consider what he adds to the fight, if its worth burning CC abilities on him, and when you should do so.

  - Rammus has strong initiation, so keep your squishies protected from a powerball+taunt.  A carefully timed CC at the start of the fight can block his initial taunt, giving you time to reposition your squishies.  During the fight, he will do constant AE damage, and will use his taunt to interrupt your channeled abilities and force target changes.  If you have someone that needs to use a channeled ult (Katarina), they may have to dance around the edge of the fight until Rammus burns his taunt (and it may never happen).  A CC may be necessary to allow her to ult.
  - Darius has a strong initiation, do not let your team get pulled.  He follows up the pull with bleed damage, snares, and great cleanup.  I'd toss CC on him at the start of the fight before he can pull, then hit him with CC again as soon as your team starts getting low on life.  If he's a fed bruiser build, I'd just keep tossing CC his way throughout.

Comment: +1 because you generalize rather than talking about darius only. It's a good question because it can be applied to many bruiser/offtank/tank champions who can get kills, like singed, jarvan etc.. Its always a dilemma whether you should actually go for them or not.

Comment: If Darius starts dunking people then his ult will refresh cooldown. Thus it will be always up, there is no wait until his ult has reset then go back in with Darius...

Comment: It doesn't refresh the cooldown.  Here's the exact text: "When Noxian Guillotine kills the target, it can be recast within the next 12 seconds. This can occur multiple times in succession."

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only truly devastating move that Darius possesses is his Ult.

Darius in particular is a single target champ that is best if he can keep the enemy target close by. His most underrated move is his E which is a pull with a surprising range. If Darius manages to pull 2 or more of your team in and land a perfect Q his team `is gona eat yo brains for breakfast even before you can say boop`. The trick against Darius is to get him stunned. There are actually allot of builds out there that focus on tanky Darius with stun and snare reduction because once again if Darius gets close your pretty much over.

t.l.d.r. : **The key counter against Darius is to stun or silence him. Stun him before he can pull you in or silence him right after he has pulled you in.**

This gives you time to get the distance you need to get. An ideal champ would be anyone with an escape or a lunge. For example Xin Zao with his ult, tristana with her cannonballs, etc. Another option would be to silence him and then mass focus him with your team. A great option would be to ult him with WW and then unleash hell.

HOWEVER, getting back to your question you stated a fed Darius in a teamfight. Im assuming a 5v5. Well it depends what the team composition is, if your got a tank on your team with a ranged attack, like Mundo try soaking his teammates. If you have a blitz or anyone with a decent pull, pull the squishy units in but only when they are out of position.

---

**Ultimatie t.l.d.r. :**

When encountering a overfed Darius in teamfights. Always target the squishy units first just like in any other teamfight (never target the tank). If Darius over extends and you have a pull, pull him in and let your team finish him quickly. If you cant kill the darius with your entire team without him having support from his team you need to reconsider your chances of actually winning. Most importantly stay passive. Dont engage, let them engage and make mistakes. Also dont commit, you dont need a more fed Darius then you already had.

I think this pretty much covers it, it's not easy to give a strategy unless you actually have all the champs to talk about but in short a tanky Darius is never the one you want to engage first in teamfights. Stay out of reach of Darius his pull. And have a lot of fun!.

Hope this helped,

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: Darius is a kill steal champion, so the chances are that he got all the kill but the rest of the team is under fed.

Comment: Besides Darius,i also seem to have trouble with tanky ap zac,nasus and sion who seem to have a way of health sustain/lifesteal and relatively short cooldown considerable damage abilities.

Comment: Although you might want a way to destroy every champ in particular, im not planning on writing one just because it cant be done. There is not a specific thing you have to do. It ALL depends on the situation and team composition. One thing every teamfight with an overfed champ have in common is that you never attack the tank first and try to pick the adc/squishy champs first. Stay passive = stay healty.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer/suggestion - **Crowd Control & Wards**.

If your team lack CC this kite him as hell using thease items; [Iceborn Gauntlet](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Iceborn_Gauntlet), [Frozen Mallet](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Frozen_Mallet) or [Rylai's Crystal Scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai%27s_Crystal_Scepter).

Use map awarnes as your supreme advantage when engaging fights that you should win.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, this relies quite a bit on team coordination. However, more important than that you must factor in the focus precedents of your ladder rating. In bronze for example, if any bruiser is fed and you attack him or her instead of the enemy carries you'll get all sorts of "DON'T FOCUS THE TANKS! NOOB!" In this case it is better to ignore and avoid the fed bruiser as best you can because keeping a higher team morale and avoiding arguments is much more important than debating high priority targets.

That said, an excellent video describing truly correct teamfight mechanics can be seen here:

.

As described in the video, the taboo of focusing tanks is very much in the wrong. Especially as AD Carry where your priority is not to take down high value targets but to deal as much damage as possible. If you go out of your way to kill the enemy squishy and die then you are no longer doing damage and no longer doing your only job. The best way to deal with a fed bruiser is for the carries to stand back and let the support peel off the enemy crash line while your own crash line tries to occupy the enemy damage long enough for you to burn their crash. If the enemy bruiser has all of the kills, the enemy damage should be pretty easy for your crash to handle alone while the enemy crash is busy chasing you around. This level of play however takes considerable coordination and doesn't work if you don't have a decent wall champion or carries with excellent kiting abilities.

If both the enemy crash line is too strong for your damage and wall and the enemy carries are too strong for your crash line then you must resort to other tactics. Fight under towers, ward up and try to catch someone separated from the group, or turtle up and split push if your team comp is capable. Sometimes though, team comps are just heavily one sided and there isn't much you can do short of hoping the enemy makes a mistake.